# Am I able to add a member-wise initializer to a Codable-conforming object?

Tags: swift, codable

I currently have a class that conforms to Codable and has an initializer like so

```
public class A: Codable {
    var aString: String?
    public init(input: String?) {
        self.aString = input
    }
}
```

When I try to create an instance of it, I get an error

```
let myA = A(input: "Goodbye world")
```

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'input:', expected 'from:')

Am I restricted to only the `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws` initializer for Codable classes?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error and to answer your question, yes you can have your own custom init methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, double check whether you actually have a public initializer not a private one.

I put this into my Xcode Playground and everything works as expected:

```
public class A: Codable {
    var aString: String?
    public init(input: String?) {
        self.aString = input
    }
}

let a = A(input: "123")
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about playgrounds - I could have easily tested there before asking. Teach a man to fish and all :) My public class and initializer were in a pod; deleting my derived data did the trick